# Function should return Promise<string>, apparently returns Promise<unknown> but still compiles

Tags: typescript

Here's a small boildown of weird code I came across. I have fixed it but I don't understand *why* it was compiling:

```js
const stringOrNull: () => Promise<string | null> = () =>
  Promise.resolve(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "Hello, world." : null);

// why does this compile?
const stringOrNullWeird: () => Promise<string> = () =>
  new Promise(resolve =>
    stringOrNull().then(result => resolve(result ? result : undefined))
  );

// will eventually crash with
// (node:20784) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLocaleLowerCase' of undefined
[...Array(10).keys()].forEach(async () =>
  console.log((await stringOrNullWeird()).toLocaleLowerCase())
);
```

I rewrote the function by simply placing the returned `Promise` inside a temporary variable so I could check the type inferred by TypeScript: it appears to be `unknown` and *then* the function does not compile.

```js
// does not compile, as expected
// Type '() => Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to type '() => Promise<string>'.
//   Type 'Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<string>'.
//     Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
const stringOrNullUnknown: () => Promise<string> = () => {
  // const p: Promise<unknown>
  const p = new Promise(resolve =>
    stringOrNull().then(result => resolve(result ? result : undefined))
  );
  return p;
};
```

So I don't understand how that second form is different from one above, and why the one above compiles, breaking type safety?

Answer (score 3):

Actually the reason is not that `Promise<unknown>` was assignable to `Promise<string>`. When you assign a `new Promise` to where an `Promise<string>` is expected, TS will figure out `new Promise(..)` is really `new Promise<string>(...)`. When you put it in a variable as in your second example, then TS has nowhere to figure out what the type parameter is and goes with `unknown`.

The real reason is this is allowed is that this is the signature for the `Promise` constructor:

```
new <T>(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void): Promise<T>;
```

Notice that for `resolve`, `value` is optional, so `undefined` is an acceptable value. This [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11094) says it fixes but then the changes were reverted due to this having unforeseen consequences in other places as described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/22772#issuecomment-382831962)

I would recommend avoiding the `Promise` constructor in general though:

```
const stringOrNullWeird: () => Promise<string> = () =>
  stringOrNull().then(result => result ? result : undefined);
```

The above is simpler and would have been an error.
Or if your async logic gets too complex use `async`/`await`:

```
const stringOrNullWeird: () => Promise<string> = async () => {
  const result = await stringOrNull()
  return result ? result : undefined;
}
```

Both would have been errors. Calling the `Promise` constructor is generally redundant.